# Anti-chain in a partially ordered set (DAG)

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, combinatorics, directed-acyclic-graphs, poset

Can anyone tell if there exists a P-time algorithm for finding a anti-chain of size k in a partially ordered set? (or a DAG)

All resources I found online deal with finding the maximum anti-chain.

Answer (score 1):

I think the formulation of the question is not precise enough since there are two parameters:

- `k` the size of the antichain;
- `n` the size of the poset `P`;

There is a clear algorithm which is polynomial in `n` and exponential in `k`:

- enumerate all the subsets of size `k` of `P`. Using some kind of gray code you can get each subset in `O(1)`. So the cost is clearly proportional to the number of k-subsets which is a binomial coefficient `choose(n, k)`. The complexity is therefore `O(n^k)`.
- for each subsets, check if it's an antichain. Assuming you compare two elements of the poset in `O(1)`. You do that in `O(k^2)`.

So the stupid algorithm as a complexity of `O(k^2+n^k)`, which is polynomial in `n`.